# How to process text from textbox/richtext box in C# using regular expression and more

Tags: c#, regex, text-processing

Original Text in the txtinput will look in this format

```
Firstportion Seconportion
Firstportion Seconportion
Firstportion Seconportion
Firstportion Seconportion
```

1. My Goal is to first split each lines into two variable and add them to an array or list or whatever works [number of lines are variable so array will not work]

   var1[] = firstportion, var2=seconportion //so far looks like working for the 1st entry
2. put those to variable array/list [Not working with the loops i currently have]
3. the process the first portions seperately and second portion seperatly with conditional if and regural expression and displaythem all back in the 2nd txtbox

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;

   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   namespace Projectx
   {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
           public Form1()
           {
           InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
           string rawInput = txtInput.Text;
           //string[] rawInput = txtInput.Text.Split('\n');
           int x = 1;
           int y = 1;
           foreach (string line in txtInput.Lines)
           {
                   string firstPortion= "";
                   string secondPortion = "";
                   string[] splitInput = Regex.Split(rawInput, ("\\s+"));
                   firstPortion= splitInput[0];
                   secondPortion = splitInput[1];
                   //##### This works so far ans splits each line into two variables seperated by 1 white space but not sure if it works for 2nd line and seems can't assign these new splited values into two seperate array or list with the same loop or seperate loop
                   //List<int> list = new List<int>; //(arr)
                   List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
                   List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
                   myList1.Add(firtPortion);
                   myList2.Add(secondPortion);

                   txtOutPut.Text = "modified " + myList1[x] + "  " + myList2[y]+"\r\n";

                   int i = 1;
                   i++;
                   x++;
                   y++;
                   }  
           }
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The List should be declared outside the loop
2. Why do you use **rawInput**? Instead you have to use **line** to do the Split
3. You dont need the local variables(x,y) instead you could use LastOrDefault()

   ```
           List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
           List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();

           string rawInput = txtInput.Text;            

           foreach (string line in txtInput.Lines)
           {
               string firstPortion = "";
               string secondPortion = "";

               string[] splitInput = Regex.Split(line, ("\\s+"));
               firstPortion = splitInput[0];
               secondPortion = splitInput[1];

               myList1.Add(firstPortion);
               myList2.Add(secondPortion);

               txtOutPut.Text = "modified " + myList1.LastOrDefault() + "  " + myList2.LastOrDefault() + "\r\n";
           }
   ```

Comment: Diffidently helped to clean up the code but still have the issue mentioned from # 2 point from original question, when it displays back the results it repeats the first item on the list over & over in every line  :: Is there any flaw how i am splitting each line into two list item

Comment: Thanks it Works "line" was the main isue

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your :

```
            List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
```

outside the foreach loop.

Comment: Helped but I am not sure If i am inserting the list items correctly cause the values form the 1st line keeps repeating and ignores all the other lines

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two big problems.

1. You're creating a new pair of lists in each iteration rather than adding new items to the same list.
2. You're splitting the `rawInput` variable in each iteration rather than the current `line`.

There are also a number of smaller ones mostly having to do with extraneous or unused variables.

Try something like this:

```
List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
int x = 0;
foreach (string line in txtInput.Lines)
{
    string[] splitInput = Regex.Split(line, ("\\s+"));
    myList1.Add(splitInput[0]);
    myList2.Add(splitInput[1]);
    txtOutPut.Text += "modified " + myList1[x] + "  " + myList2[x] + Environment.NewLine;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Diffidently helped to clean up the code but still have the issue mentioned from # 2 point from original question, when it displays back the results it repeats the first item on the list over & over in every line

Comment: Thanks it Works "line" was the main isue